# Neo4j: is there a way to optimize input for CSV LOAD, like regex?

Tags: regex, csv, neo4j

I have a a csv file (now I am only working on 1 row of it), with lots of similar headers:

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ load csv from "file:///...libreof.csv" as csvLine return csvLine[7],csvLine[8], csvLine[9], csvLine[11],csvLine[12], csvLine[13];  
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| csvLine[7]     | csvLine[8]     | csvLine[9]     | csvLine[11]    | csvLine[12]    | csvLine[13]    |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| "names_0_lang" | "names_0_text" | "names_0_type" | "names_1_lang" | "names_1_text" | "names_1_type" |
| "la"           | "Fabariense"   | "orig"         | "de"           | "Peffers"      | "orig"         |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Until now, in order to create nodes  with properties I had to enter the command for each of the column, which is pretty time consuming when there are about 50 of them:

```
using periodic commit load csv with headers from "file:///...csv" as csvLine                                
> create (pl_name:placeName { name:csvLine.names_0_text, lang:csvLine.names_0_lang, type:csvLine.names_0_type})  
> create (pl_name:placeName { name:csvLine.names_1_text, lang:csvLine.names_1_lang, type:csvLine.names_1_type})
```

resulting in:

```
neo4j-sh (Fabariense,1)$ ls
==> :placeName
==> *lang =[la]      
==> *name =[Fabariense] 
==> *type =[orig]   

neo4j-sh (Peffers,2)$ ls
==> :placeName
==> *lang =[de]      
==> *name =[Peffers] 
==> *type =[orig]
```

Is there a way to optimize the loading of data from csv? 
To use something like regex `'r'names_\d+_text'`, `'r'names_\d+_type'`, `'r'names_\d+_lang'` and to load everything matching in the line at once and not one by one?

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to reformat your csv files e.g. using unix command lines tools to have a separate line for each person?